# LOC constraint value

Tags: xilinx

I'm trying to program a constraints file for a XC2C256-7VQ100, hence I used a line like follows:

```
NET "led_1" LOC=7;
```

However with the above I get an error during translate saying:

```
Error: Constraint 'LOC' has a value '7' which is invalid. Use the following:
Text that matches the regular expression: *i!:^(soft)|(hard)|(level)$
```

However I cannot find anywhere information on what soft/hard/level means and/or why I can't just use the pin number specified in the XC2C256 data sheet. Could someone shed some light on this for me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax for LOC is:

**NET   "LED_1" LOC =   "7";**

Try this, and I am sure your problem will be solved.

Comment: I think I actually managed to solve the problem by doing LOC=007. I'll try your method tomorrow though as there is some other issue that might be resolved doing that...